# Polynomial inequalities in ordered fields

Tags: non-archimedean-fields

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial over an ordered field. If $p'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ in an interval over that field, is it true that $p(x)$ is increasing over that interval?

Comment: Don't we have arbitrary order integration formulae with positive rational coefficients and "rational" nodes? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I am asking if this is true in non-Archimedean fields, i.e. can this be proved purely algebraically.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Isn't it true that $1>0$, so $m>0$ for all positive integer $m$, so $q>0$ for all positive rational $q$, so if $b>a$, then $p(b)-p(a)=(b-a)\sum_j q_jp'(a+r_j(b-a))>0$ for any rational positive coefficient quadrature formula of order greater than the degree of $p$?

Comment: The answer to the OP is certainly 'yes' in the case of real closed fields, since these are elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$. Hopefully an affirmative answer can be obtained by exploiting the fact that each ordered field embeds in a real closed field.

Comment: @fedja: I think it would be great if you could expand your comments into a proper answer. (And yes, a polynomial identity with rational coefficients like this holds automatically in all ordered fields if it holds in the reals.)

Answer (score 3):

It is remarked in *A Course in Model Theory: An Introduction to Contemporary Mathematical Logic* by Bruno Poizat, page 101 ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=_WXgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=ordered+field+positive+polynomial+real+closure&source=bl&ots=fVmDLefOQ7&sig=6yU1w_JolanxyhkkG6Tn1lOjBxc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBWoVChMIuJ3Ru9O_yAIVhns-Ch0x-AZG#v=onepage&q=ordered%20field%20positive%20polynomial%20real%20closure&f=false)), that the assertion is true for all ordered fields, but that its proof is difficult. He gives the proof for real closed fields just prior to that remark.

Comment: Todd, the remark is, indeed, there but I still wonder what subtlety I'm missing if any because the argument I proposed is totally trivial :-(

Comment: @fedja I have to confess that I didn't understand your argument. What if the coefficients of $p$ aren't rational?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: What fedja suggested would amount to this in the degree $2$ case (as an illustration): we have the identity $p(b)-p(a)=((b-a)/2)(p'(a)+p'(b))$ for all $p$ with $\deg p\le 2$. Obviously, this holds in all characteristic $0$ fields (just check it on monomials), and the OP's claim is immediate now.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks; that's very helpful indeed. That does seem like a promising idea (wonder what could go wrong?!).